# Where is the smart contract is stored

Tags: smart-contract

I would like to know where the smart contract is stored after the copilation and deployment.

Thanks

Comment: You should be more specific. Do you mean on the blockchain? Or on the file system? If so, what build system do you use? EOS Studio?

Comment: thanks for your comment, @Abhijit Roy has already given the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EOS smart contract is stored in the account's RAM space. The SC is uploaded in in '.wasm' & '.abi' formats.